# Language in VueJS from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vuejs2, vue.js

I am trying to load locale language variables from a JSON Request (laravel generated) to VueJS since VueJS does not support locale out of the box. The ready function alert does not alert but the random text data variable does work. I know VueJS is loading correctly. There are no console errors and webpack compiles the vue. The lang array says empty and the lang.email shows blank. This is my issue. Any help appreciated.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      lang: [],
      randomtext: 'This is Random Text'
    },
    ready: function() {
      alert('THIS DOES NOT ALERT');
      this.getLanguage();
     },
     methods: {
       getLanguage: function() {
         this.$http.get('/lang/auth').then((response) => {
            this.$set("lang", response)
          }, (response) => {
            alert(response);
          });
       }
     }
});
```

the 'lang/auth'

```
{"email":"Email Address","password":"Password"}
```

my html:

```
 <h5 class="content-group">@{{ randomtext }}</h5> // This Works
 <input type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="lang.email"> // This does not
```

Comment: Which version of vuejs are you using? Are you using 2.x?

Comment: @MacPrawn I am running 2.0.1

Comment: Ok - "ready" was deprecated in 2.0... Try with "mounted" instead -- see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced

Comment: @MacPrawn thank you that was the issue. I was looking at a tutorial and the version was not mentioned in it.

Comment: Since a valid answer was provided, maybe @MacPrawn can put it as answer, so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered

Comment: Thank you @NelsonRodriguez - I just added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, "ready" was [deprecated in Vue.js 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced)

Try using "[mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)" instead.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, Change `ready:` into `mounted:`

(Because, vuejs version 2 doesn't support it anymore)

**Second**, Instead of using `this.$set` use `this.lang = response`

Here is the full code
https://jsfiddle.net/uqp7f4zL/